# Method with primitive argument using PrivilegedAccessor

Tags: java, junit, nosuchelementexception

Within my Junit, I am trying to execute a Method using `PrivilegedAccessor` as following but getting `NoSuchMethodException: Invalid Method getInsurance` -

```
PrivilegedAccessor.invokeMethod(InsuranceRetriever,
                    "getInsurance", new Object[] { code}, new Class[] {
                            Long.class});
```

Following is the tested method declaration.

```
private InsObj getInsurance(long code)
```

*Please note here that i am passing Long.class whereas the real argument is primitive long. How to pass primitive argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
PrivilegedAccessor.invokeMethod(InsuranceRetriever,
                "getInsurance", new Object[] { code }, 
                new Class[] { Long.TYPE });
```

Explanation:

The class objects for the primitive types are found under the TYPE static final constant in each of the java.lang objects for each of the primitive types. `Boolean.TYPE`, `Integer.TYPE`, `Byte.TYPE`, `Short.TYPE`, `Long.TYPE` etc.